# How to get number of CPU's logical cores/threads in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

How I can get number of logical cores in CPU?

I need this to determine how many threads I should run in my application.

Comment: It's OS-dependent, so what OS?

Comment: Any Windows that supports .net 3.5

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get number of logical processors  through the Environment class
number of cores:

```
int coreCount = 0;
foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get())
{
    coreCount += int.Parse(item["NumberOfCores"].ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine("Number Of Cores: {0}", coreCount);
```

number of logical processors

```
foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem").Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number Of Logical Processors: {0}", item["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"]);
}
```

Environment.ProcessorCount

```
 using System;

 class Sample 
 {
     public static void Main() 
     {
        Console.WriteLine("The number of processors on this computer is {0}.", 
           Environment.ProcessorCount);
     }
 }
```

go through this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx

Comment: I have no ManagementObjectSearcher object in System.Management. Why?

Comment: @Kamil: check Assembly:  System.Management (in System.Management.dll)

Comment: @Kamil: check it is in  System.ComponentModel.Component

Comment: I tried Environment.ProcessorCount, looks OK, i have 2 cores detected on Core Duo T2500 CPU. I have to try this on quad core xeon with HT.

Comment: I found and added reference to that dll. It also works, but much slower than Environment.ProcessorCount. What is the difference? I know why WMI technique works slower, but can results differ? Will Win32_ComputerSystem work on Windows 64?

Answer (score 30):

Use the [Environment.ProcessorCount property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx), it returns the number of logical cores.

Comment: Thanks @MikeT, but i had to accept answer that took author little more time. Your answer is satisfying too.